# How to subtract 1 day from current date time in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a current datetime with followint function :

```
String cdate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now());
```

Now I want to subtract 1 day or 24 hours from this current date time.

How can i do that?

Comment: Whatever answer you choose, please keep in mind that for much of the world, a single day isn't always 24 hours.  Some of them are 23 hours and others are 25 hours, as the Daylight Saving Time transitions. Always do your date arithmetic in "utc" to prevent issues with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't manipulate the string, manipulate the date. From [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/DateTime-class.html#using-datetime-with-duration), adapted:

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final yesterday = now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
```

Apply the formatting just before you need to display the date, not before.

Answer (score 4):

Date manipulation methods are provided by the DateTime class. Refer to [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) documentation. Checkout [now](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.now.html), [add](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/add.html), [subtract](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/subtract.html).

The following code shows how you can achieve what you want:

```
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  String cdate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(today);

  DateTime yesterday = today.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
  String ydate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(yesterday);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code also refer [add](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) and [subtract](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/subtract.html) for DateTime

```
void main() {
  var date = new DateTime.now();
  date = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day - 1);
//  or use subtract method also like below
 //final day= date.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
  print(date);
  print(day);
}
```

Result using `day-1`:

```
2022-09-13 00:00:00.000
```

Result using `subtract method` :

```
2022-09-13 12:52:45.734
```